# How to test React Native Camera with E2E Detox with Mocha Runner

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox, react-native-camera

I am working one project for E2E testing react native with Detox but find a problem. 
I can not mock my camera to deal with detox E2E. Some of the documentation is there but it is hard to implement once there no working stuff. Any help would be appreciated :)

[image]

The image above demonstrates how my E2E testing works. I want to take the picture from a react-native camera.

This my last code snippet

```
describe('Pickup', () => {
  it('should change 1012 to 1023', async () => {
    await element(by.id('tab_pickup')).tap();
    await element(by.id('list_broadcast_pickup_0')).tap();
    await element(by.id('btn_accept_request_pickup_0')).tap();
    await element(by.id('btn_yes_start_pickup')).tap();
  });

  it('should select the camera’, async () => {

  });  
});
```

Comment: Explain your scenario a bit. What are you trying to test exactly? And where are you stuck?

Comment: hi @AndreOlar. question edited. Please kindly see :)

Comment: finally found it. just create the camera component with extension e2e after that run your react native package with e2e. Finally when the component clicked just set the value to your state

Comment: Did you get any help with this?